# Making java react to a spike in outgoing sound

Tags: java, javasound

I'm trying to beat a game made by my friend.
The game goes as follows:

A baby will spawn at a random location on my screen. i then have to move the mouse over it, and react,by clicking it, as soon as it starts to scream.

I have used the java.awt.Robot to manouver the mouse the the baby.

My problem now, is that i wan't to click it whenever the sound spikes, by setting a threshold of some sort, but i cannot find a way to measure outgoing volume.

I have tried to utilize javax.sound.sampled.*, but that only lets me access the sound from the microphone.

Ideally there would be a fuction like LineOut.GetVolume(), but i doubt i am that lucky :P

Any suggestions on how to access the outgoing volume in java, would be greatly appreciated :D

Kind Regards Frederik

Comment: Isn't volume controlled at OS level?  Also the way you described the game makes it sound like whack-a-baby, which is mildly disturbing... just kidding...

Comment: it is a whack a baby game :p we just make stupid games for each other to practice programming, and finding ways to program solutions :P I believe the volume is controlled at OS level, but i don't want to control it, i just want to react to a change in it :)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html It seems like you can switch from microphone to the proper line?

Comment: i cant switch the line i am recording :/ i can get info of the speakers by doing: Port line = (Port) AudioSystem.getLine(Port.Info.SPEAKER);, but cant seem to find the volume anywhere :/

Comment: The Java Sound APIs will only tell you about sounds being made by the current JVM. They won't tell you anything about sounds from other programs, not even the volume.

Comment: Are you complete sure about that? The only other solution i can think of, is checing the pixelvalues of the volume slider that is build into windows, and that is far from ideal :P

Comment: From the line that has audio info, I believe you are going to have to decode it from bytes into PCM values, and calculate and monitor a rolling root-mean-square of the values to obtain a relative volume. A TargetDataLine is used to get the audio stream and an example of how to do so is on the tutorial link given by rilent above.